# Why MVC keeps route values in URL without passing them directly

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes, url-routing, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a question.
Let's say I have this routes:

> /Guest/{var1}/{var2}
>
> /Guest/{var1}/{var2}/edit

When I'm on the `/Guest/123/321` page, I have a link to `/Guest/123/321/edit?id=1`.
There is a form on the page `/Guest/123/321/edit?id=1`, which posts itself on the same address.

Let's say that my Actions looks like:

```
public ActionResult Index(int var1, int var2)
{
    /* here is some a business logic */    
    return View(model);
}

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
    /* here is some a business logic */
    return View(model);
}


[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(EditModel model)
{
    /* here is some a business logic */
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

The question is why do I have URL `/Guest/123/321` after `RedirectToAction("Index")`, after I submit the form? I mean - it's awesome. It reduces the code a lot. I just don't like to use methods, that I don't understand. :)

I always thought, that I should pass something line new `{ var1 = 123, var2 = 321 }` to `RedirectToAction` in order to keep the URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a confusing part of MVC that was previously reported as a bug<sup>1</sup> because many people don't find this behavior to be natural. But according to Microsoft, this behavior is by design.

> 1. Unfortunately, the Codeplex issue URL was taken down and is not in the Internet archive.

The behavior is that route values are *reused from the current request* when they are not supplied explicitly.

There are some cases where it works well, such as [localizing the URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32764989/asp-net-mvc-5-culture-in-route-and-url#32839796), but in other cases such as when [using Areas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34467408/what-is-the-purpose-of-area-in-an-html-actionlink/34467809#34467809), you have to manually clear the value in the `ActionLink` to be able to access the default area.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Application name", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, null)
```

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't able to find any documentation about this and it was a bit confusing.