# Root level Action links are getting appended with Area name in Asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have this code structure, a Home controller at root level and another Home controller at Area level. One of the answers on SO helped me to solve *the Multiple controller name error* but what I am not getting is why the root actionlinks are appended with Area name once Area views has been visited.

[image]

**_Layout.cshtml**

```
  <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("AuthorCF", "Index", "AuthorCFs")</li>

                        @*Area*@
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Service Requests", "Home", "ServiceRequests")</li>

                    </ul>
                </div>
```

When I click on Service Requests I am able to visit Service request Index page But when I hover over About/Contact link, I see *"http://localhost:62864/ServiceRequests/Home/Contact"* , why the ServiceRequests is getting appended ?

**Please let me know if I need to ask this more clearly.**

Comment: `@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" })`

Comment: This url says "http://localhost:62864/ServiceRequests/Home?Length=4" and on click it stays on same Area page.

Comment: Sorry, forgot t include the necessary 5th argument - `@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, null)`

Comment: Thanks for help Stephen! That solved.

Comment: Your might find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34525244/why-mvc-keeps-route-values-in-url-without-passing-them-directly/34525675#34525675) and its links useful to better understand the behavior